# qemu cannot boot kernel version 2.6.34.7

Tags: compilation, kernel, qemu

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 and trying to boot kernel 2.6.34.7 compiled from source. I tried to boot from ubuntu but it says "kernel too old", then I came up with the idea of using qemu, but I got the same problem... The version of my QEMU emulator is 2.11.1, the error code is:

```
...
FATAL: kernel too old
[          5.299747] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
[          5.300415] Pid: 1, comm: init Not tainted 2.6.34.7 #1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with QEMU. The "FATAL: kernel too old" message comes from your guest's userspace, specifically its glibc. Your guest's userspace binaries were built to require a newer kernel than the one you're trying to boot, so the two are not compatible. You need to either use a set of userspace binaries (ie a disk image) which was built to work with that old kernel, or you need to use a newer kernel that will work with the binaries you're using.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I don't think I should use a newer kernel, so how should I build a disk image to work with that old kernel?

Comment: Should I use a lower version of gcc to recompile the kernel source?